# How to optimize trace of inverse in CVXPY?

Tags: python-3.x, cvxpy, convex-optimization

How can I formulate an objective function that minimizes the trace of an inverse matrix using cvxpy?

Concretely the following problem:

[image]

[image]

subject to:

[image]

I have seen the trace_inv objective function in cvx but so far was not able to figure out how to translate this to cvxpy.

Comment: Please consider asking such questions in an SE site that allows MathJax.  To understand the motivation for my suggestion, try to read this question in "night mode"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

*Edit:*
They just released CVXPY 1.3 with the objective function tr_inv().

https://www.cvxpy.org/updates/index.html#cvxpy-1-3

https://www.cvxpy.org/api_reference/cvxpy.atoms.other_atoms.html#tr-inv

---

I figured it out by looking at the source code on github, https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/tree/master/cvxpy/atoms.

The function `matrix_frac()` fits the problem.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import cvxpy as cp

n = 20
k = 5

A_list = []
for i in range(n):
    A = np.random.uniform(0,10,(6,6))
    A_list.append(A.T@A)

# Create two scalar optimization variables.
z = cp.Variable(n)

# Create two constraints.
constraints = [z >= 0,
               z <= 1,
              np.ones((n,))@z == k]

cost = sum([z[i] * A_list[i] for i in range(n)])

# Form objective.
obj = cp.Minimize(cp.matrix_frac(np.eye(6), cost))

# Form and solve problem.
prob = cp.Problem(obj, constraints)

prob.solve()  # Returns the optimal value.

print("status:", prob.status)
print("optimal value", prob.value)

# compute trace of inverse using z
S = np.zeros(A_list[0].shape)
for i in range(len(z.value)):
    S += z.value[i] * A_list[i]
value = np.trace(np.linalg.inv(S))

print("value", value)
print(prob.value == value)
```

Output:

```
status: optimal
optimal value 0.02061809722699777
value 0.02061809722699777
True
```